# Showing the document after modification

Tags: jsoup

After I made many changes to the HTML document using JSoup so what I did is 
I have a peocessing page where I fetch the page from the website and insert some tags to the head as follow:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
 Element head=doc.select("head").first();
  ...etc
```

I want to display the document as an HTTP response (what I mean how to display the page in the browser)
I read about JSOUP but I could not find anything related to displaying the HTML document after making some modification!!

please I need help or guide and if my understanding is not good please tell me a good book 
to start learning JSoup

Comment: Jsoup document parses the data and if you make any changes(i don't know whether it will change) then the change will not be affected on the url page.You take the data and do whatever you like.The url doesn't know about it.anyways jsoup with what(android,java,..) ?

Comment: @bachayer
I got stuck in the same situation where you were. Just curious to know how you solved the above issue?? If you have an answer then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't insert tag. It actually fetches selecting html element by matching the tag.Jsoup is a unidirectional thing.It doesn't send data to the actul page.

For better understanding

see these

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

http://desicoding.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-parse-html-in-java-jsoup.html

to show complete page in java see below

http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/display-web-page-in-jpanel-in-applet-504590.html

To display webpage in android

[webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)